# How to make gulp.series wait until files are created on previous tasks

Tags: npm, gulp

I'm currently using something like this:

```
gulp.task('js', gulp.series('js-a', 'js-b', 'js-c'));
```

The task `js-c` requieres `js-a` and `js-b` to be executed first and to generate 2 files than then I combine in `js-c`.

However, no matter if I use `gup-series`, the function `js-c` gets executed before the two files from the previous two tasks are created.

How can I tell gulp series to wait for those?

I've read other related issues but they tend to rely on external scripts to accomplish this. 
I manually managed to fix this by adding a `setTimeout` on `js-b`, but seems like a hacky solution.

Is there any proper way to accomplish this with gulp.series?

To put you in context, the task `js-a` looks like this:

```
var gp_concat = require('gulp-concat');

gulp.task('js-a', function(done) {
    gulp.src([
            'file1.js',
            'file2.js'
        ])
        .pipe(gp_concat('tmp.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./'));

        done();
});
```

And I am now forced to use a timeout to fix this issue:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    done();
}, 500);
```

Comment: That's weird, would mean one of the core concepts of gulp not working, which doesn't seem likely. Have you e.g. checked your `js-a` and `js-b` tasks for possible async operations that are not awaited for?

Comment: The tasks are executed in series, that's true, but the file generated by the 1st task gets created later one, when we are in the 2nd or 3rd task.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`done()` shouldn't be used in this case and the task should return the stream (see [here](https://gulpjs.com/docs/en/getting-started/async-completion/)). Please try this:

```js
var gp_concat = require('gulp-concat');

gulp.task('js-a', function() {
    return gulp.src([
            'file1.js',
            'file2.js'
        ])
        .pipe(gp_concat('tmp.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./'));
});
```

Comment: Yeap, that's it! Thanks a lot for that!! :)
I assume I can call "done" on the last task, right ?

Comment: The only probleem I'm finding is how to make it work when using thing such as `require('child_process').exec` that won't return a steam.

Comment: @Alvaro Not sure about calling `done()` on the last task - it is certainly not needed if it returns a stream so it may only cause issues. For anything not returning a stream, `done()` would work if you can call it when the process finishes. But I would probably take a look if there is gulp plugin doing the same task first.